# Blank sign in page

Tags: wp-admin, debug, troubleshooting, fatal-error

I have a serious problem with my wordpress site.
When I try to enter into my wp-admin page, I get blank page.

I tried every solution possible including: deactivate plugins, update to higher wordpress version, deleting doubles spaces in wp-config and wp-function, added debug function to wp-config, and nothing helped.

How else can I resolve this?

Comment: What can you see on that page when it's opened in View Source mode?

Comment: When you say blank page, you mean the white screen of death, correct? Has this site's wp-admin worked at some point before it became blank? And so it was blank, and you upgraded WordPress to a newer version and it's still blank? This sounds like a PHP error - also check the console for JS errors in your browser inspector. Also try setting a default WordPress theme if you're using a custom one (e.g. TwentyThirteen/Fourteen).

Answer (score 0):

is your site working? or problem it's just with admin? try to review apache access & error logs for possible clues. Try also to review htaccess, bad rewrite could break your site

Comment: Thank you all!
Well.. this is the situation: my site is still working, the problem is just to enter into my dashboard..
Indeed, I'm using custom theme, but even if I'm trying another theme (i.n. Twenty Thirteen/Fourteen), the problem is still remain.